# IAP Mock Library

Tags: windows-phone-8, mocking, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on the Microsoft website that shows you how to add the Mock project to my project. I'm not sure how to add a project to my original project and link the Class files. It asks me:

> As an alternative to testing in-app purchase by creating a Dev Center beta app, you can add the mock in-app purchase library to your solution. In Visual Studio, add the mock in-app purchase library as an additional project to your solution.

But I'm not sure how to. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You add project by rightclicking in you solution and adding the solution file of the iap mock library. Using the dev account you have to create a beta in upload a product list. But basicly step by step follow [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)